# Positive integer values for volume of a box

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

does anyone have a suggestion for an algorithm for the number of positive integer values for the sides of a box with a given Volume? So the diophantine equation l*w*h=V, where V is given. So for V=1 there are three different solutions (1,1,3 & 1,3,1 & 3,1,1).I'd like to be able to tell how many solutions there are for a given V.

Comment: Do you mean "So for V=3 there are..."? [rather than V=1 etc]

Comment: Yeah, I want to find for V=x, how many possible solutions are there

Comment: https://oeis.org/A007425

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
$$
V=\prod_{p_i\in\mathbb{P}} p_i^{s_i}
$$
the prime factorization of $V$. There are 
$$
\binom{s_i+3-1}{3-1}
$$
possible ways of distributing the powers of $p_i$ across the factors $l$, $w$ and $h$. Therefore the overall number of solutions is
$$
\prod_i \binom{s_i +2}{2}
$$